# Use multiple databases in CodeIgniter without the config file

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Im new to CodeIgniter, and im building a project where I need to acces roughly 40 databases.

Now adding them all to the config file seems like allot of inneficient work, also there will be more databases added in the future.

Is there a way to acces a database within the codeigniter framework without using the database configuration settings?

Thanks in advance!

Greetings,

Beakerv

Comment: So, where will you store the database login information then? You will have to put them somewhere...

Comment: Good point, is it possible to use something like a connectionstring within the codeigniter framework? Just as you would in regular php without codeigniter?

Comment: Yes you can use DSN in codeigniter or you can make custom config for your connection just refer to codeigniter tutorial here https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can achieve what you want

```
class Your_Model extends CI_Model
{
    protected $customDb;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->loadCustomerDatabase();
    }

    private function loadCustomerDatabase()
    {
        //define your customers database
        $config['hostname'] = 'localhost';
        $config['username'] = 'myusername';
        $config['password'] = 'mypassword';
        $config['database'] = 'your_db';
        $config['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
        $config['dbprefix'] = '';
        $config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
        $config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
        $config['cache_on'] = FALSE;
        $config['cachedir'] = '';
        $config['char_set'] = 'utf8';
        $config['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

        $this->customDb = $this->load->database($config, true);

        //you can use this instance like any other db instance
        $objQuery = $this->customDb->select("*")->from("your_table")->get();


    }
}
```

Comment: Ah cool, I didnt knew that! Now is it possible to make the $config['database'] = 'your_db'; <- a variable value? So I can modify the database that is selected on input from a dropdown?

Comment: of course its possible - just replace this string with a declared variable